# How can I get the dimensions of the current font in a terminal?

Tags: terminal, console, xterm, ncurses

I am working on an ncurses application that creates some very blocky graphics using alphanum characters. I'd like to be able to detect the dimensions (specifically the aspect ratio) of the font glyphs so that I can correct for it by changing how I render my graphics (such that a square always looks like a square).

I am able to use the

```
void getmaxyx(WINDOW *win, int y, int x);
```

function in ncurses to get the size of the screen/window, but since many windows can be freely resized, it, it's not reliable. Is there a similar function (or external mechanism) for retrieving the font dimensions?

Comment: What you your terminal emulator? `konsole`? `xterm`? Something else?

Comment: I use xterm and sometimes the console. I'd like a solution that can handle both, or two solutions I can combine together.

Comment: How would the font dimensions help you? What matters is the number of columns/lines in the terminal (that, as you said, could be obtained using `getmaxyx`). The font size could be larger or smaller, but it doesn't affect the display, only the lines and columns do. If you resize the window, the font will remain the same, but the number of lines and columns change so you'll need to redraw your graphics anyway.

Comment: Because not all fonts are the same aspect ratio. Terminal dimensions are only helpful if the font aspect ratio remains the same.

Comment: It still doesn't matter. The terminal dimensions show you the number of columns and lines. Columns = the width of the terminal **by characters**. So if columns = 80, it means that the width of the terminal is exactly 80 characters, regardless of the size or the aspect ratio of the font. Same goes for the number of lines. A line is always at the height of a single character, the font has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The fonts in the terminal are **always** [monospace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font?wprov=sfla1). Maybe that's what you didn't understand?

Comment: My question asked specifically if there was a way to get the dimensions of the console font. If you're not interested in answering that question, please spare me your half-baked thoughts on the matter.

Comment: No need for insults. I was trying to help. I actually spent some time to look for an answer, trying different approaches, and when I couldn't find one I started to wonder why you need it, because it didn't seem relevant. I'm seriously interested in knowing how the font dimensions matter. Give me an example, a drawing, anything. Maybe I'm missing something, and I hate missing things. If you convince me you need it, and on the way will teach me something I didn't know, I'll make an extra effort to help you. The fact I'm still trying even though you're an a**hole indicates how serious I am.

Comment: On a 1920x1080 terminal window:

An 8x16 (WxH) font makes 240 columns by 67 rows
An 8x12 font makes 240 columns by 90 rows.

Just knowing the terminal columns and rows doesn't help because different fonts have different aspect ratios which yield different rows and columns for the same sized window.

Answer (score 3):

With `xterm` or compatible and provided font operation escape sequences have not been disabled:

```
$ xtermcontrol --get-font
DejaVu Sans Mono
```

That sends the `<ESC>]50;?<ESC>\` escape sequence, and the terminal replies with `<ESC>]50;font-name<ESC>\`. See [reference](https://www.invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-5-0.1019).

So you can also query it with `zsh` for instance with:

```
$ IFS=$';\e' read -rsd'\' -t0.2 $'font?\e]50;?\e\\' font font rest
$ typeset font
font='DejaVu Sans Mono'
```

`allowFontOps` is generally disabled by default though. You'd set the `*allowFontOps: true` resource to enable them or preferably keep it disabled but set `*disallowedFontOps: SetFont` to allow `GetFont` but not `SetFont`.

For the size, set the:

```
*disallowedWindowOps: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,13,19,20,21,GetSelection,SetSelection,SetWinLines,SetXprop
```

resource, that is disallow all but `GetWinSizeChars` and `GetWinSizePixels`, then with `zsh`:

```
$ IFS=';t' read -rsdt -t0.2 $'x?\e[18t' cy cx rest
$ IFS=';t' read -rsdt -t0.2 $'x?\e[14t' y x rest
$ echo ${x}x${y} ${cx}x${cy}
1916x1012 147x38
```

`\e[18t` requests the window size in number of cells, `\e[14t` in number of pixels so you can get the size of a cell with:

```
$ printf '%gx%g\n' '1.*x/cx' '1.*y/cy'
13x26
```

Answer (score -2):

Hello from the sunny Athens.
Unfortunately things like font_size, or various fonts, or things like that, have unfortunately to do with   loading the graphical driver for the HW and applying it as a graphical environment, that is loaded ONLY, when you use the graphical environment from Linux and not from the console (alphanumeric mode only) or using CTRL+T for enabling a terminal during a Windows session in any case.
The only possibility to use different font sizes, it could be  through ncurses, but according to POSIX standards, this is not possible.
If you want to apply in any case different font sizes, there are many environments like **processing** supported by java, which will give you a solution. Greetings from Athens
Kostas Vergidis

Comment: No, the Linux console (without a graphical environment) is capable of using various fonts, and their size isn’t fixed.

Comment: Hi kosta, and welcome to the site! As Stephen points out, I'm afraid this is wrong, which is why you're getting downvotes. Don't take it personally, it's about the answer, not you! Also, please avoid writing things that aren't directly relevant to the post. We try to keep things direct and to the point and regularly remove greetings, thanks etc. That's so we can help others find the information they need as efficiently as possible (δεν είμαστε απλώς στριμμένοι, δηλαδή, έχουμε λόγο!).